# python finding number of attack per day per ip

Tags: python, logging

hey i am trying to find many attacks were logged per day per ip. i am reading from a syslog file.

here a line couple lines am reading from

Quote ...

```
Jan 10 09:32:09 j4-be03 sshd[3876]: Failed password for root from 218.241.173.35 port 47084 ssh2
Jan 10 09:32:19 j4-be03 sshd[3879]: Failed password for root from 218.241.173.35 port 47901 ssh2
Feb 7 17:19:16 j4-be03 sshd[10736]: Failed password for root from 89.249.209.92 port 46139 ssh2
```

This is my code:

```
desc_date = {}     
count_date = 0
desc_ip = {}
count_ip = 0

for line in myfile:
    if 'Failed password for' in line:     
        line_of_list = line.split()     
        #working together
        date_port = ' '.join(line_of_list[0:2])
        date_list = date_port.split(':')
        date = date_list[0]
        if desc_date.has_key(date):
            count_date = desc_date[date]
            count_date = count_date +1
            desc_date[date] = count_date
            #zero out the temporary counter as a precaution
            count_date =0
        else:
            desc_date[date] = 1

        ip_port = line_of_list[-4]
        ip_list = ip_port.split(':')
        ip_address = ip_list[0]
        if desc_ip.has_key(ip_address):
            count_ip = desc_ip[ip_address]
            count_ip = count_ip +1
            desc_ip[ip_address] = count_ip
            #zero out the temporary counter as a precaution
            count_ip =0
        else:
            desc_ip[ip_address] = 1

        resulting = dict(desc_date.items() + desc_ip.items())
        for result in resulting:
            print result,' has', resulting[result] , ' attacks'
```

currently giving me these results which is wrong:

Quote ...

```
Feb 8 has 33 attacks
218.241.173.35 has 15 attacks
72.153.93.203 has 14 attacks
213.251.192.26 has 13 attacks
66.30.90.148 has 14 attacks
Feb 7 has 15 attacks
92.152.92.123 has 5 attacks
Jan 10 has 28 attacks
89.249.209.92 has 15 attacks
```

which the ip addresses are wrong and not sure where going wrong in code hope someone can help

Comment: Why do you think the IP addresses are wrong?

Comment: It would help us if you edited your post to make sure the code was indented correctly.

Comment: because for example JAN 10 - got 28 attacks so i need each ip address per day to match the 28 attacks

Comment: Are the input lines sorted by date?

Comment: Just to be sure you understood Asker's question, let me rephrase: when you look at the log file, do you find that the dates and times are not all in chronological order?

Answer (score 4):

Try this solution, I tested it with sample input in the question and works fine:

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict
pattern = re.compile(r'(\w{3}\s+\d{1,2}).+Failed password for .+? from (\S+)')

def attack_dict(myfile):
    attacks = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
    for line in myfile:
        found = pattern.match(line)
        if found:
            date, ip = found.groups()
            attacks[date][ip] += 1
    return attacks

def report(myfile):
    for date, ips in attack_dict(myfile).iteritems():
        print '{0} has {1} attacks'.format(date, sum(ips.itervalues()))
        for ip, n in ips.iteritems():
            print '\t{0} has {1} attacks'.format(ip, n)
```

Run it like this:

```
report(myfile) # myfile is the opened file with the log
```

Comment: you could use `pattern.match` in this case. `date, ip = found.groups()` might be more readable

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Thanks for your suggestions, I edited my answer accordingly

Answer (score 2):

I see two problems.  1) You are counting up attacks by day, by IP and by port, all separately; no association is made between an attack from a given IP and the date of the attack. 2) Iterating through the items in the dictionary, as you have done in

```
resulting = dict(desc_date.items() + desc_ip.items())
for result in resulting:
    print result,' has', resulting[result] , ' attacks'
```

will give cumulative numbers of attacks in an essentially random order, freely mixing attacks-by-date with attacks-by-IP.  The fact that you see

```
Feb 8 has 33 attacks
```

...followed by

```
218.241.173.35 has 15 attacks
72.153.93.203 has 14 attacks
213.251.192.26 has 13 attacks
66.30.90.148 has 14 attacks
```

...does not mean that those attacks by IP occurred on Feb 8.

The 15 attacks from 218.241.173.35 represents the total number of attacks from that IP throughout the entire period covered by the log file.  It is by chance that the line for 218.241.173.35 occurred after Feb 8, and not before, or after some other date.

Comment: How would i achieve this i know excatly what you mean but unsure how to achieve it

Comment: How I would proceed depends on the answer to the question I asked in the comment on your main post (about sort order).  Sorry that I asked in a different place; it seemed like a question of general relevance, but perhaps you missed it because of that.

Answer (score 0):

Waning: untested code.

```
attacks = {}

# count the attacks
for line in file:
    if 'Failed password for' in line:
        date = re.match(line, '^(\w{3}\b\d{1,2})\b').group(1)
        attacks_date = attacks.get(date, {})
        ip = re.match(line, '\b(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\b').group(1)
        attacks_date[ip] = 1 + attacks_date.get(ip, 0)
        attacks[date] = attacks_date

# output results
for item in attacks.items():
    date, attacks_date = item
    print date, 'has', attacks_date.values().sum(), 'attacks'
    for attack_item in attacks_date.items():
        ip, n = attack_item
        print ip, 'has', n, 'attacks'
```